# Wacom CTL-472 Tablet gets hang randomly with NVidia driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, wacom, nvidia-geforce

I'm using a Wacom CTL472 Graphic tablet with Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel `5.11.0-38-generic`). When I was using Intel Onboard graphics (Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake). It was perfectly working fine. Then I installed a driver for my graphics card ie. NVIDIA Corporation GM108M GeForce MX130. The system now gets heated up, the fan is rotating at high speed and the graphic tablet pen gets hung randomly at different time intervals. After 4 or 5 seconds, the control will be back, and then again after some time, it will get hung.

Nvidia graphics driver is installed from `software-properties-gtk` --> Additional drivers.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, it should work fine. I had problems with the wacom tablet being in android mode before, so maybe it could be that.

Check to see if the wacom tablet works on the settings, and if the tablet gets recognized correctly. If that does work, I suspect the problem has more to do with the nvidia drivers, so try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: How to check if tablet is in sndroid mode ? Updation of driver is done.

Comment: you can check if tablet is in android mode by looking at the LED indicator. If its barley on, its in android mode, if it is bright, it should be in normal mode.

Comment: How to switch the mode ?

Comment: https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500006332582-How-can-I-manually-switch-the-Wacom-Intuos-into-Android-mode- works for both going into, and out of

Comment: This is another model. Not CTL-472